# Inherated classes that differ in one property

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a domain model class like below:

[image: Domain model]

Two implementations are considerable:

***1)*** The Letter class specifies that the message is a letter and its children specify the type of the letter. The only difference between class **IntraOrganization** class with **InterOrganization** is the type (in the Letter class ) and the Sender (in the Message class).

The type in the Letter class can be one of the below enum:

```
enum LetterType {
    IntraOrganization = 1,
    InterOrganization = 2
}
```

I can set the type of each class in the constructor like:

```
class IntraOrganization : Letter {
    public IntraOrganization() {
        this.Type = LetterType.IntraOrganization;
    }
}
```

***2)*** But another implementation is considerable. If no class is inherited from Letter and the type of each one is set in the constructor like:

```
// Intra organizational
Letter intreOrgLetter = new Letter(LetterType.IntraOrganization);

// Inter organizational
Letter interOrgLetter = new Letter(LetterType.InterOrganization);
```

Which design is better?

Comment: If they don't have different behaviour then why would you create different classes for them. Just keep the enum as a property.

Comment: @FCin There is a tiny difference which I didn't explained more for simplicity. The sender of  IntraOraganization and InterOrganization are from different type of a base class which named **Identity**

Comment: In my opinion 1st approach is more preferable, as it encapsulates the enum and type assignment.

Comment: The first option (if you made `Letter` abstract) gives you all of the benefits of the second, plus some extra benefits (e.g. down the track you could have different implementations of functionality in `IntraOrganization` and `InterOrganization`).

Comment: @mjwills I am myself prefer the first approach, but what if the domain model is going to be mapped into relational db ?

Comment: You need to spell out all of your constraints. If that is important, you need to mention it in your question. Otherwise, we are all playing a fun game of 'guess what I am thinking'. _Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application._

Comment: This is all just guessing. There is no real problem here and you are trying to predict future. Implement a solution that is the simplest to expand.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the factory pattern to determine if the object should be made as one type or the other, and make two classes InterOrganization and IntraOrganization, which both inherit from letter.

solution done, and your have the ability to do anything you want really without any restrictions. Best I can come up with, without more information from you about the overall design.

Because you shouldn't have a Type added to a class that is already a type? Why would you? your type has already been determined.